# What happens if nobody wins?

Tags: saboteur-2

If you create a path to the gold with a blue door in the way, and there are no blue dwarves, no boss, and no profiteer, what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game designer, **Frederic Moyersoen**, [discusses the answer to that question on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/6675274#6675274) (emphasis mine).

If there is a path with a blue door, the blue gold-diggers win (and not the green). If there are no blue gold-diggers, no profiteur and no boss, **nobody wins**.